# How do I deal with a MySQL Error Number 1040: Too many connections?

Tags: mysql, jsp

I am using two database connections to achieve a particular task. Everything is working fine, but I am displaying data using paging and while going to the next page sometimes MySQL crashes.

After that, when I open the MySQL database by using localhost/xampp/url it gives me the below error:

`#1040 Too many connections`

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are many opened conenctions. You should close them in application after using.

Another variant is to setup [wait_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) server variable - *the number of seconds the server waits for activity on a non-interactive connection before closing it*. Not used connections will be closed automatically.